# 3D Viewport artifacts. Geometry looks teared

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am modeling this object, and all of a sudden this started to happen, all edges and geometry looks teared, but geometry it self is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is "Start clipping" distance which is found in View tab. in my case it was set to 0.001 cm.